# yum security plugin questions

Tags: security, redhat, yum, update

When i run "yum updateinfo list available", many packages are listed

`[apcon@localhost ~]$ sudo yum updateinfo list security all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
i FEDORA-EPEL-2014-4045       security libvncserver-0.9.9-0.9.el7.1.x86_64
i FEDORA-EPEL-2015-22f9be240b security qemu-common-2:2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64
i FEDORA-EPEL-2015-22f9be240b security qemu-system-x86-2:2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64
updateinfo list done`

However, when I run "yum update --security", it saids "No packages needed for security".

`No packages needed for security; 595 packages available`

If "updateinfo list security" detects packages that are tagged security updates, shouldn't "yum update --security" pick it up and update it?

Comment: Are any of those packages installed?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you are right, it seems those packages are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out packages are already installed